# Filter records from parent table to appear in the "Add new" page as a select list

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have two tables: `customer` and `city`. I have `customer.city_id` field as a foreign key that references `city.id`.

```
class Customer(model.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city_id = models.ForeignKey(City, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id'
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'customer'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(model.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    added = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # value is 1 or 0
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'city'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I add a new customer, I can pull all the records (city names) and display them in the add new customer page. How can I get only the cities that their `city.added` value = `1` and ignore those with value `0`, Preferably in the `models.py` file or in the `admin.py` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted out with the [get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) function. This is how I did it (in the *`CustomerAdmin`* class):

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(CustomerAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['city_id'].queryset = City.objects.filter(added=1)

    return form
```

It's amazing how easy it is to miss things in front of us when working for more than 30 hours continuously!